# Can resources from 2 separate templates be deployed into the same resource group

Tags: powershell, azure, templates

I want to deploy resources in different templates to the same resource group (same subscription).

Example: 
 
- Template 'A' contains definitions for storage account 1, nic 1, vm 1,
   etc.
 
- Template 'B' contains vm 2 which should use storage account 1.
 
- Deploy template 'A' to resource group 'RG', then deploy 'B' to resource group 'RG'

I'm seeing the exception 'The storage account named xxx12345vhd1 already exists under the subscription.' Which is true after deploying template 'A', but I don't understand why the exception is being thrown - AFAIK that is the desired behavior.
I have tried copying the json from template 'A' to 'B' for the storage account; using 'dependsOn' resourceId, or reference().

Comment: Please share your arm templates in your question.

Comment: Hi, could you give me more detailed information about your issue.